# Need to mock out some base class behavior in a python test case

Tags: python, inheritance, super, base-class, python-mock

My title is fairly descriptive, but here goes.
Suppose I have this setup.

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def base_function(self, param="Hello World"):
        print param

#multiple inheritance probably irrelevant but my problem deals with it
class DerivedClass(BaseClass, AnotherBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def advanced_function(self):
        #blah blah blah
        #code code code
        self.base_function()
```

Now, I have a situation where I am testing a derived class, but in doing so, I need to ensure that it's base class methods are called. I tried doing something like this

```
from mock import MagicMock

d = DerivedClass()
super(DerivedClass, d).base_function = MagicMock()
d.advanced_function()
super(DerivedClass, d).base_function.assert_called()
```

I'm 100% sure this setup is wrong, because

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'base_function'
```

I know I'm doing something wrong with super, anyone have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried accessing `BaseClass.base_function` directly, rather than via `super`?

Comment: This works. Why? I thought I needed to use a specific instance of the class. How does setting BaseClass.base_function to equal MagicMock make all derived instances mocked out as well?

If you have a link to read explaining all this, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access via `BaseClass.base_function`. As you don't overload the method, you just inherit it, the `DerivedClass.base_function` is the same object:

```
id(BaseClass.base_function) == id(DerivedClass.base_function)
```

When the instances are created, they inherit the mock.