# How to mock a base class's method when it was overridden?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, mocking

I have a code similar to this:

```
from mock import MagicMock


class Parent(object):

    def test_method(self, param):
        # do something with param
        pass


class Child(Parent):

    def test_method(self, param):
        # do something Child-specific with param
        super(Child, self).test_method(param)
```

Now I want to make sure that `Child.test_method` calls `Parent.test_method`. For this, I'd like to use `assert_called_once_with` from the [mock](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) module/library. However, I cannot figure out a way to do this. If the method would not be overridden by the subclass this would be easy as pointed out by [Need to mock out some base class behavior in a python test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530921/need-to-mock-out-some-base-class-behavior-in-a-python-test-case). However, in my case this is the same method, so what do I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [patch.object](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object):

```
with mock.patch.object(Parent, 'test_method') as mock_method:
    child = Child()
    mock_param = mock.Mock()
    child.test_method(mock_param)
    mock_method.assert_called_with(mock_param)
```

Comment: This method is working for any method of the super class isn't it ?

Comment: @Romain, yes, it works for both overriden and not overriden methods, if that's what you mean.